# Build and move by ftp auto after push to github

Tags: angular, github, build, ftp

Is it possible that in GitHub we define the command for when push the angular project to a repo, GitHub auto build and deploy project by FTP to the server?

Comment: You could probably use something like [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky) ?

Answer (score 0):

The term you are searching for is Continuous Integration which you can you can search.

For FTP you can use -

[git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp)